# Doctrine - best way to check for a record, then either update or add

Tags: model, doctrine

I've come across this scenario a few times in working on a current project. I have to see if a record exists then if it doesn't I need to add it, if it does then I need to update. What is the standard way of doing this with Doctrine?

I seem to be querying to see if the record exists using a find* method. Then if that returns a positive result (object), I use that object to update. Otherwise, (no record found) I have to create another object and save().

For some reason this just seems inefficient. Is there a better way or am I just being weird? :)

```
$user = Doctrine_Core::getTable('Model_User')->findOneByEmail('myemail@email.com');
if (!$user) {
    $user = new Model_User();
    $user->fromArray($values); // $values comes from form or wherever
    $user->save();
} else {
    $user->fromArray($values);
    $user->save();
}
```

Comment: or this great answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14781688/doctrine-check-if-record-exists-based-on-field

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to be that you're just making it a little verbose :) This is pretty "clean" I think:

```
$user = Doctrine_Core::getTable('Model_User')->findOneByEmail('myemail@email.com');
if (!$user) {
    $user = new Model_User();
}
$user->fromArray($values); // $values comes from form or wherever
$user->save();
```

---

You *could* roll your own:

```
class Model_UserTable extends Doctrine_Table {
    ...

    public findOrCreateOneByEmail($email) {
        $user = $this->findOneByEmail($email);
        if (is_null($user)) {
            $user = new Model_User();
            $user->email = $email;
        }

        return $user;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I guess you are right. I like the first option. Not sure why I duplicated the save() code.

Comment: I find this specific kind of "utility" functions to be more disturbing than helpful, too :)

Comment: @mattalexx It boils down to the need for reuse, I guess. If it's a one-off I'd go with the easily readable first option. If I could use a `findOrCreateOneByEmail` method multiple places, I'd add the method to the `Model_UserTable` class.

Comment: @jensgram If you're just saying that you'd like it better in the Table class, I totally agree.

Answer (score 1):

I've wrote my own method in the needed sfDoctrineRecord class.

```
public function saveOrUpdate(Doctrine_Connection $conn = null) {
    $object = Doctrine_Core::getTable('TableAlias')->find(array($this->getKey1(), $this->getKey2()));
    if (!is_object($object)) {
        $object = $this;
    }else{
        $object->setVar1($this->getVar1());
        $object->setVar2($this->getVar2());
        $object->setVar3($this->getVar3());
        $object->setVar4($this->getVar4());
    }
    $object->save();
}
```