# Doctrine - check if record exists based on field

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Using doctrine in symfony2, i have a simple user model with the following fields:

```
Username
Email
Password
```

How can I load the model based on email address?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
$user = $this->getDoctrine()
             ->getRepository('YourBundle:User')
             ->findOneBy(array('email' => $email));
```

Please read [the official doctrine orm documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html#by-simple-conditions) about this

Comment: This does not only check if the record exists. It retrieves the record and populates an entity instance, which incurs significantly more overhead than simply checking it's there.

Comment: @Bananaapple the question is "How can I load the model based on email address?"

Comment: @seferov - absolutely, hence no downvote or anything :-) Just wanted to point this out for anyone coming across this looking for a way to assert a record exists as suggested by the title.

Comment: To add to this, after stumbling over my own comments a year later - here is how to check if a row exists without the overhead of pulling in the entity when it isn't needed: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36801089/doctorine-check-if-record-exists-in-database#comment94987732_36802084

Comment: `$availableNickname = 0 === $em->getRepository('MyProject\Domain\User')->count(['nickname' => 'nonexistent']);`